# how to set maximum selection of checkbox in a dialog in advanced installer 8.9?

Tags: advanced-installer

```
                             Advanced Installer 8.9
```

---

### I have 9 check-box on a selection dialog ,on which i need to allow maximum selection of any three check-boxes.

We can show a message box displaying that only three can be selected or disable next button .

Trying to do permutation and combination will be a filthy task,is there any way where i can set a counter which increments on selection of check-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a very [simple custom action in C#](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html) that checks the value of each property attached with your checkboxes. You need to [call this DLL using a published event](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-execute-ca.html), from each checkbox, so when a user tries to select it, first the custom action checks to see if other checkboxes are not selected. If there are already 3 checkboxes selected then you need to delete the property of the new checkbox, like this:

```
session["CHECKBOX_PROP_1"] = "[~]";
```

Of course you can also use a [C++ custom action](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1747/MSI-Custom-Action-DLL) if you prefer this language.